# UIWebView - force navigation in safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView in objective-c that loads an external HTML with an embedded video (I have no access to this HTML). This video has a pre-roll ad from Google Ads (but can be from another provider in the future). 
This ad has a link to an external website that the user can click but it seems to be triggered by a javascript event (not a regular  anchor).

I have set the delegate in order to force clicked links in the webview to open in Safari, but these links from the ads keep opening inside the webview. I think it's because they are triggered from javascript.

This is my delegate:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:
(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }
return YES;
}
```

Does anyone knows of a way to force any navigation outside the domain loaded in the webview to open in Safari? I guess this way I could circumvent this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you know the "internal" domain ahead of time, you could force all external domains to open in Safari:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (![request.url.absoluteString containsString:@"https://www.yourinternaldomain.com"]) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

**Update:**

Based on your comments, if the above won't suffice, you could add a `UITapGestureRecognizer` to detect user input:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapGesture.delegate = self;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

Implement the delegate methods to ensure your tap is recognised:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    return YES;
}
```

In your `-tapGesture:` method, you can then set a temporary `BOOL`:

```
-(void)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGesture {
    self.userDidTap = YES;
}
```

And then in the subsequent `-webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method, you can inspect the `self.userDidTap` value and act accordingly:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {

    if (self.userDidTap) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[request URL]];
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I also thought though of this, but the URL loaded in the webview is served to the app by an api call, and can be different all the times. Is there a way to know the actual domain loaded in the app at the moment of the click request in order to know if it's different or not?

Comment: Could you store the initial URL received from the API as a property, and compare that host (NSURL -host method) to the one in [request URL]?

Comment: I guess I could, but the number of webviews loaded is unknown. I do a call to an api that can return one URL to load in a webview, or many... All with possible different URLs...

Comment: Understood. I've updated my answer with an alternative solution. Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't test right now, but seems promising! Thanks!